# Why my Azure functions are not visible in the function list after my deployment from GitHub/Kudu?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my first HTTP trigger Function App to Azure.

It was created with the Azure Function extension in VS Code with TypeScript template.
I use my GitRepo as a source and the Kudu build App Service.

My functions are working well locally. I can see them in VS Code > Azure tab, Local Project > Functions.

I have no error on the deployment itself but I cannot see my two functions in the Azure Functions list.

In the kudu UI, I see that all my files are correctly deployed :
[Kudu screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcayl.png)

My settings are :
[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUWqc.png)

Where can I find some logs on what went wrong? Any idea of other things to check?

Any help will be appreciated.

I could use Zip deploy (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push) as an alternative way to deploy this (I haven't tried it yet). I would like to know what's wrong with my current setup.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot for your Function App -> ***Functions*** page on Portal?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the problem is that you configure the wrong runtime.

Here is the steps I did:

1. Create a Function app project with an http-trigger function based on TypeScript in VS Code:
   [image]
2. Upload the project to GitHub.
3. Using deployment center to configure deploy from Git on portal.
   [image]
4. After deploy, check in Functions page:
   [image]

---

By the way, you could deploy from VS Code directly:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Indeed, going through Azure Pipelines is the workaound I finally applied. My intial question was more about the step I missed for a deployment using Kudu : I was clearly missing the "npm build" part in Kudu (so no dist folder to deploy) but I still don't know why.